# Joining the same table 2 times, then summing up -> doubles the actual wanted value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have a SQL query that looks like this:

```
select L.ID, P.FIRSTNAME as Firstname, P.LASTNAME as Lastname, SUM(R.VAL), SUM(R2.VAL) from LABORATORY L
join RESULT R
    on L.ID=R.ID 
    and R.RESID='Thingy1'
join PERSON P
    on P.PERID=R.PERID
    and P.LASTNAME={Lastname} <-this is part of the framework I'm working with and gets replaced, don't worry about it
    and P.FIRSTNAME={Firstname}
join RESULT R2
    on R2.PERID=P.PERID
    and R2.RESID='Thingy2'
```

Now since I'm joining the Result Table 2 times, both sums are double the value they should be. If I leave the SUMs I get this table as a result.

---

123 Manu Dreier

234 Michael Schuhmacher

423 Barrack Obama

123 Manu Dreier

234 Michael Schuhmacher

423 Barrack Obama

---

Sorry I don't know how to correctly display a table here :P

As you can see, every value in this table appears 2 times. If I add "distinct" there is only 3 values( correct ) but the value of SUM is still doubled. Any clue about what I could do about this would be helpful. With count I can actually write:

```
count(distinct L.ID)
```

But this doesn't work with the sums since some people have identical values (like age for example). Summing up distinct ages to get the total peoples age doesn't work ;)

Comment: why are you joining your table two times? and where is your group by opereator? what is your sample output?

Comment: Because it's a table of results and I'm retrieving two different results (of which I build the sums). There is a variable number of results for each element in the system which is why it was done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be dealing with a N-M join. To avoid double-computing `SUM`s, one solution is to move the aggregate query to the `JOIN`s, like so :

```
select 
    L.ID, 
    P.FIRSTNAME as Firstname, 
    P.LASTNAME as Lastname, 
    R1.sum_val, 
    R2.sum_val
from LABORATORY L
join (SELECT ID, SUM(VAL) sum_val FROM RESULT R WHERE RESID='Thingy1' GROUP BY ID) R
    on L.ID=R.ID 
join PERSON P
    on P.PERID=R.PERID
    and P.LASTNAME={Lastname}
    and P.FIRSTNAME={Firstname}
join (SELECT PERID, SUM(val) FROM RESULT WHERE R2.RESID='Thingy2' GROUP BY PERID) R2
    on R2.PERID=P.PERID
```

With this technique, aggregation happens within the joined subqueries, and does not affect the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

You should join the subquery for sum

```
  select L.ID, P.FIRSTNAME as Firstname, P.LASTNAME as Lastname, r1.sum_1, r2.sum_2
  from LABORATORY L 
  INNER JOIN (
    select  ID, PERID,  SUM(VAL) sum_1
    from RESULT 
    where RESID='Thingy1'
    group by ID, PERID
  ) r1 on r1.PERID = P.PERID AND r1.ID = L.ID
  INNER JOIN (
    select  ID, PERID,  SUM(VAL) sum_2
    from RESULT 
    where RESID='Thingy2'
    group by ID, PERID

  ) r2 on r2.PERID = P.PERID AND r2.ID = L.ID
  INNER PERSON P ON P.PERID = r1.PERID
```